# ArchUnit: Run @BeforeEach method before @ArchTest rules

Tags: java, junit, junit5, archunit

I'm using [ArchUnit](https://www.archunit.org/) to test the layer architecture in one of my projects. Therefore I use the `@ArchTest` annotation on static final `ArchRule`s like described in the [user guide](https://www.archunit.org/userguide/html/000_Index.html#_using_junit_4_or_junit_5).

The tests work fine, but now I try to run a method that is annotated with JUnit5's `@BeforeEach` annotation to log some information about the test and it seems that the **`@BeforeEach` method is not executed before the `@ArchTest`s**, but only before the tests that use a *JUnit test method* (see example below).

```
/**
 * Tests the project architecture using ArchUnit tests.
 */
@AnalyzeClasses(packages = ProjectArchitectureTest.PROJECT_ROOT, importOptions = {DoNotIncludeJars.class})
public class ProjectArchitectureTest {
  private static final Logger log          = Slf4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(ProjectArchitectureTest.class);

  public static final String  PROJECT_ROOT = "my.project..";

  /**
   * Should be executed before each test, to log some information about the current test.
   */
  @BeforeEach
  public void beforeEach(TestInfo testInfo) {
    log.info("Running test: " + testInfo.getDisplayName()); // log some information about the test
    
    fail("test before each"); // let the test fail (to check whether this method is executed before the test)
  }

  /**
   * An ArchTest rule using a static final ArchRule and the ArchTest annotation.
   * This test won't fail, because the beforeEach method is not executed before this test.
   */
  @ArchTest
  public static final ArchRule LAYERS = freeze(layeredArchitecture() //
      .consideringOnlyDependenciesInAnyPackage(PROJECT_ROOT, "") //

      .layer("controller").definedBy("my.project.controller..") //
      .layer("service").definedBy("my.project.service..") //

      .whereLayer("controller").mayNotBeAccessedByAnyLayer() //
      .whereLayer("service").mayOnlyBeAccessedByLayers("controller") //
  );

  /**
   * An ArchUnitTest using a JUnit test method.
   * This test fails (as expected), because the beforeEach method is executed before the test.
   */
  @Test
  public void testLayers() {
    JavaClasses importedClasses = new ClassFileImporter().importPackages(PROJECT_ROOT);

    ArchRule rule = classes().that().resideInAPackage("my.project.controller..") //
        .should().onlyAccessClassesThat().resideInAPackage("my.project.service..");

    rule.check(importedClasses);
  }
}
```

Is there a way to execute the `@BeforeEach` method before each of the `@ArchTest`s?
Or is there a similar ArchUnit specific annotation for cases like this?

Comment: I don't think that the [`ArchUnitTestEngine`](https://github.com/TNG/ArchUnit/blob/main/archunit-junit/junit5/engine/src/main/java/com/tngtech/archunit/junit/internal/ArchUnitTestEngine.java) from ArchUnit's JUnit 5 support currently executes anything other than `@ArchTest`-annotated ArchUnit tests. What's your use case for `@BeforeEach`?

Comment: @Manfred It's main purpose is to log some information about the test that is executed (name, tags, ...)

Comment: Have you tried the JUnit Platform listeners yet? They should also work with the ArchUnit engine. https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-listeners

Comment: @RolandWeisleder It seems that the listeners are only called before the test methods too.